# Is it ok to bring a mirror onto an international airplane (US - POL)

Tags: air-travel, regulations, hand-luggage

I am leaving to poland in a few days. I wonder if its ok to bring a mirror onto an airplane. 
If so what are the dimensions that are allowed??

The flight is from US to Poland through Germany

Comment: Why would bringing a mirror be an issue in the first place?

Comment: @MastaBaba: Broken glass can do the job of a knife and bringing a knife is an issue.

Comment: Are knives an issue? I understand some airlines hand them out in business class. (I don't mean the plastic ones.)

Comment: http://www.tsa.gov/travelers/airtravel/prohibited/permitted-prohibited-items.shtm - Knives - except for plastic or round bladed butter knives Carry-on No (also comments are not places to ask questions just start another question or look for if one was already posted)

Comment: @hippietrail: True. It's the same as the question on bringing a pen, which was asked earlier. And it's the same with any glass objects. Like, perhaps, computer screens. Or framed photos (which do get accepted as hand luggage).

Comment: @MastaBaba: Well it's certainly *like* the question about the pen. Not sure it's the same though unless we are all expected to be familiar with the wording of all the airlines bizarre carry-on policies. For instance bringing a plastic knife aboard could just as easily be considered the same as bringing a metal knife aboard.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are talking about a personal mirror like the one ladies carry in their purses, then it's fine. But if you are talking about a large mirror like the ones to be hanged on the wall, then it's a different story.

My day-to-day job is about this kind of things. There is nothing clear regarding Glass or Mirrors. For example, Glass bottles are totally fine, while the airplane's mirrors are made of a non-glass based material. Considering the aviation safety textbooks as the source, the only things that can restrict you from bringing your mirror on board are:

- Sharp edges. Mirrors are not mentioned specifically but in general most sharp items are not allowed.
- Dimensions. Maximum allowed length for most airlines is 45 linear inches (the total of the height, width, and depth of the bag). Anything larger should be checked.
- Weight. The heavier the item is, the more dangerous it is if it falls from the overhead compartments in case of turbulence or incidents. Most airlines have a limit for carry-on luggage but it's different from one airline to another.

A personal advice to you is, do not bring it on board, the chances of having the mirror broken are not much greater if you check it in rather than take it on board. Plus I do not think the airport security and/or the airline staff will allow you to carry it even if there is nothing in the books to prohibit mirrors explicitly. Personally, if I was operating on that flight, I would definitely ask the ground staff to offload it because I have seen what real turbulence would do and the last thing I would want to see is pieces of glass flying all over the cabin.

To check it in, put it in a foam box or something similar, stick that *fragile* sticker and hopefully it will make it. Or just buy a new mirror in Poland ;)

Here are some resources:
[Preparing to Fly](http://www.faa.gov/passengers/prepare_fly/)
[Prohibited Items](http://www.tsa.gov/travelers/airtravel/prohibited/permitted-prohibited-items.shtm) 
[Carry-On Baggage Tips](http://www.faa.gov/passengers/prepare_fly/baggage/)

Comment: Who knew there'd be such a good answer to this question?

Comment: thank you a lot. The reason i was considering bringing a mirror is because its really long flight and my girlfriend has to braid her hair and it literally takes days. There is nothing else to do on a plane and she cant braid without a mirror. Thank you for a detailed answer :)

Comment: Trust me if you have your girlfriend on board you can do a lot ;)

Comment: haha :) You're right but its nice to have a plan B. (pun not intended)